# Async/Await how to handle with "old" results?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I have a async Load function to call a `WCF` Service and then do some stuff with the results.

```
protected async void Load(bool reload)
{
     var items = await GetItems(skip, take, SearchString);

     OnItemsLoaded(items);
}
```

Load can be called multiple times, even if the old loading isnt completed.

Example:
Call 1 => Call 2 => Result from Call 2 => Result from Call 1

This is why I used `Task` and `ContinueWith` to check the Thread ID and discarded the "old" results. 
But I want to change this to Async/Await pattern.

There are two scenarios:

1. `Reload` is true: All old threads/results should be discarded. Only the "latest" results should be processed.
2. `Reload` is false: All threads/resuls should be processed.

Comment: You could await on a tuple of GetItems and a sequence number, probably allocated using something Interlocked (and allowing for overflows!) or you could pass a sequence number into GetItems and have it return that in a structure with the collection of items?

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be achieved using cooperative cancellation mechanism, implemented by `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource`.

What you need to do is pass a token to your method and *monitor on that token* while doing your work. If a user requests cancellation, you cancel the operation.

```
private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
protected async Task LoadAsync(bool reload)
{
     if (reload)
     {
        cts.Cancel();
     }

     var items = await GetItems(cts.Token, skip, take, SearchString);
     OnItemsLoaded(items);
}
```

And inside your `GetItems` method, you'll need to monitor on that token:

```
public async Task GetItemsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      // Do some work.
   }

   // This will cause the task to transfer to a cancelled state, if needed.
   cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();     
}
```

Note i changed `LoadAsync` to return `async Task` instead of `async void`. The latter is meant only for top level event handlers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I cannot change anything inside `GetItems`. The problem is how to determine if it should cancel Call1, Call2 etc...
My Idea was to check if there is a newer context when the await comes back and then decide what to do. Maybe there is a possibility to work with the `SynchronizationContext`?